# Prove that $ f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)\sin\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ extended by $f(0,0)=0$ is differentiable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Prove that $  f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> (x^2 + y^2)\sin\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$}  \\
> \end{cases}$ differentiable.

I tried to use the definition:

$$\lim_{{h \to 0}\\{, k\to0}} \frac{f(x+h, y+k) - f(x,y) - f'_x(x,y)h - f'_y(x,y)k}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} = 0.$$

Started by find the partial derivetives:

$$f'_x = 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}) - (x^2 + y^2)\frac{2x \cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} = \dots = 2x\bigg(\sin(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}) - \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})}{x^2 + y^2}\bigg)$$

$$f'_y = 2y\bigg(\sin(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}) - \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})}{x^2 + y^2}\bigg).$$

Plug into the equation again, and it seems to be very long.

Is there any theorem or something like that, that can ease this process?

Comment: **Hint** The $x^2+y^2$ gives the impression that this function is radially symmetric about $(0,0)$. Thus, the substitution $r=x^2+y^2$ may help.

Comment: Indeed, with @Daryl’s suggestion (except that I’d set $r^2=x^2+y^2$), and since the only problem is at the origin, the verification should take only a few lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ if there exists a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-T(h)|}{\Vert h\Vert }=0
$$
For $x=(0,0)$, let $T=0$, that is, the zero transformation. Then, we have
$$
\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-T(h)|}{\Vert h\Vert }= \frac{\Vert h\Vert^2 \sin(\Vert h\Vert ^{-2})}{\Vert h\Vert}= \Vert h\Vert |\sin(\Vert h\Vert ^{-2})|
$$
Because for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus {(0,0)}$, we have $f(x)= \Vert x\Vert^2 \sin(\Vert x\Vert ^{-2})$.
Then,
$$
0\leq \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-T(h)|}{\Vert h\Vert }= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\Vert h\Vert | \sin(\Vert h\Vert ^{-2})| \leq \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\Vert h\Vert= 0
$$
Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $x=(0,0)$. At every other point, the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous and then $f$ is differentiable at every point of its domain.